# How to redirect all request to index.php even with .php in the url

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx vhost config:

```
server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name blocked_server;
        root /home/gian/blocked_server;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ / {
                try_files $uri $uri /index.php;
        }
}
```

it redirects all urls to index.php except when the url ends with .php extension.

for example this works:
http://localhost/somethingthatdontexist

but this returns a 404 and don't redirect to index.php
http://localhost/somethingthatdontexist.php

how can i redirect url with .php extension that don't exist to index.php?

Comment: Try adding `try_files $uri /index.php;` to your `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: i tried adding it to the `location ~\.php$` block and I can't reload nginx due to this error:  `nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5`

Comment: Check the contents of the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file. You can either change the `try_files` statement in there, or paste the contents of the file into the `location` block so you can edit it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved the problem.
First you should comment out this line or remove this line from the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
```

then on your virtualhost config put `try_files $uri $uri /index.php;` before the `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` on the `location ~\.php$` block.

the `location ~\.php$` block should look like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri /index.php;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: or you can just set the error 404 page to be index.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments made on the original question by @Richard Smith (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) are very important and should be added as an answer.

Adding try_files to the .php location is the answer but it results in an error because that option is already set in the included snippet.

Simply editing /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf and changing the try_files option to your desired outcome resolves the problem.